# How do you change the text size in the content assist window in Flash Builder 4.7?

Tags: flash-builder, content-assist

I'm working on a Mac ox 10.8.3 with Flash Builder 4.7 and the content assist window all of the sudden has tiny unreadable text. Any way to make it larger?

[image: Content Assist window with tiny text]

Answer (score 1):

Check "Preferences" -> "Colors and Fonts" -> "Flash Builder" -> "ASDoc display font"

[image]

Comment: Could you mark your question as solved, so that anyone else with this problem has it easier :) ?